# App is published in Android Market but not visible in some phones

Tags: android, google-play, publish, htc-android

I have application published in the market. Below is the link provided. I have HTC Wildfire and Desire with me. Both have android 2.2

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.cricket.fast

Now I can see this and install this application on HTC Desire, but I cant see this in market on HTC Wildfire.

But If I install app manually, it works, then why it is not listed for HTC Wildfire in the market ?

While  building application my target SDK is 8 and minSDK is 3.

Whats the problem here. Can some one please look at the link and help me ?

**[Updated] Below is the manifest code. I have removed my 6 activities while copy-pasting here**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.cricket.fast"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="0.1">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:name=".DashboardActivity"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
    <uses-permission xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>   
</manifest>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the manifest file? You can skip the parts with the activities.

Comment: If you have the supportscreens in the manifest, you should check that this is not blocking the application for small screen devices like wildfire.

Comment: I have added the manifest code in the question. Please check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filtering on the Android Market is done according to a few tags in your manifest file. The rules are described here: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/market-filters.html

I think the wildfire is a "small screen". If so, you need to explicitly enable this setting in the manifest:

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens=true />
```

I had the same problem with the X10 mini at one point.

Comment: Thanks :) 
Let me try and check the stuff you gave.

Comment: Yes, you could also set your targetSdkVersion on the uses-sdk element higher and then it would default to true as well. You don't currently have a target so it may default to your minSdkVersion, which is 3, which would not support small screens by default.